# Read and Merge Two Yaml Files Dynamically and/or Recursively

Tags: go, yaml

[This question has been answered for merging top level map[string]interface{} values for two yamls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947879/read-and-merge-two-yaml-files), but is it possible to merge two yaml files

A. without defining structs and

B. with multiple unknown levels of nesting?

I tried unmarshalling into the same blank interface, but the override yaml completely wiped
the base yaml.

```
// using "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

var i interface{}

d, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("base.yaml")
yaml.Unmarshal(d, &i)

d2, _ = ioutil.ReadFile("override.yaml")
yaml.Unmarshal(d2, &i)

m, _ := yaml.Marshal(i)
ioutil.WriteFile("new.yaml", m, xxxx)
```

The new written file is just the `override.yaml`.

How can I merge two yaml files that have nested values with a depth unknown without defining structs to encapsulate their bodies? Do I need to to perform a custom recursive operation or can this be handled with tools already built?

Comment: Merging two yamls files won't be a simple code, there is a tool [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) for merging yamls. This is also written in Go. You can take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of completely unmarshaling the YAML files, you should only *compose* them. In YAML terms, this means constructing a node graph, without processing it further (usually, the node graph would then be processed into native types). go-yaml provides the type `yaml.Node` for that but you'll need the unstable `v3` version.

After both files are available as nodes, you simply implement the merging operation on them, e.g.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"
)

var input1 = []byte(`
a: b
c:
  d: e
`)

var input2 = []byte(`
c:
  f: g
h: i
`)

func nodesEqual(l, r *yaml.Node) bool {
    if l.Kind == yaml.ScalarNode && r.Kind == yaml.ScalarNode {
        return l.Value == r.Value
    }
    panic("equals on non-scalars not implemented!")
}

func recursiveMerge(from, into *yaml.Node) error {
    if from.Kind != into.Kind {
        return errors.New("cannot merge nodes of different kinds")
    }
    switch from.Kind {
    case yaml.MappingNode:
        for i := 0; i < len(from.Content); i += 2 {
            found := false
            for j := 0; j < len(into.Content); j += 2 {
                if nodesEqual(from.Content[i], into.Content[j]) {
                    found = true
                    if err := recursiveMerge(from.Content[i+1], into.Content[j+1]); err != nil {
                        return errors.New("at key "+from.Content[i].Value+": "+err.Error())
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
            if !found {
                into.Content = append(into.Content, from.Content[i:i+2]...)
            }
        }
    case yaml.SequenceNode:
        into.Content = append(into.Content, from.Content...)
    case yaml.DocumentNode:
        recursiveMerge(from.Content[0], into.Content[0])
    default:
        return errors.New("can only merge mapping and sequence nodes")
    }
    return nil
}


func main() {
    var v1, v2 yaml.Node
    yaml.Unmarshal(input1, &v1)
    yaml.Unmarshal(input2, &v2)
    if err := recursiveMerge(&v1, &v2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    e := yaml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    e.Encode(&v2)
    e.Close()
}
```

This code outputs

```
c:
    f: g
    d: e
h: i
a: b
```

As you can see, it merges values both at the top level and inside `c:`. Theoretically, you need to implement `nodesEqual` also on sequence and mapping nodes because those can also be keys, but this feature is rarely used so you can leave it out if you don't need it. This code also merges sequences by simply concatenating them into a single sequence, this may or may not be what you want. More code is required if you want to also properly process alias nodes.