# yaml anchor and alias - partial override

Tags: yaml

I have to structures that are pretty similar but differ only in a leaf node of the corresponding tree, like A1.AB.ABB in the example.

```
A1:
  AA:
    AAA: true
    AAB: true
  AB: 
    ABA: true
    ABB: true 


 A2:
  AA:
    AAA: true
    AAB: true
  AB: 
    ABA: true
    ABB: false
```

What I am looking for is a way to reduce repeating code by using the first structure (A1) as a template for the second ONE (A2) with only specifying the structure of the leaf that gets overriden. In the example given, the whole 'AB' Branch gets replaced and that is what I want to avoid.

---

```
A1: &A1
  AA:
    AAA: true
    AAB: true
  AB: 
    ABA: true
    ABB: true 


 A2:
  <<: *A1
  AB: 
    ABB: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with YAML. Even the merge key `<<` has only been specified as optional extension for outdated YAML 1.1. YAML is a data description language, not a data processing language.

You can, of course, write some code to do it for you. [Here is an example how to do it in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65768861/347964).

Answer (score 0):

```
A1: &A1
  AA:
    AAA: true
    AAB: true
  AB: &AB
    ABA: true
    ABB: true 


 A2:
  <<: *A1
  AB: 
    <<: *AB
    ABB: false
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).