# Merging two yaml documents while concatenating arrays

Tags: yaml, yq

I want to merge two yaml documents with the result containing

- all mapped values (with the last one taking precedence)
- concatenated arrays

e.g. given this file

```
# file1.yml
animals:
  - elephant
    donkey
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - chocolate
strange: true
```

and this file

```
#file2.yml
animals:
  - monkey
    pelican
flavours:
  sweet:
    - vanilla
strange: false
```

the result should contain all the nodes, with merged arrays and values that are not arrays from the last file

```
#result.yml
animals:
  - elephant
    donkey
    monkey
    pelican
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - chocolate
      vanilla
strange: false
```

Can yq do this, maybe?

Comment: My experience with yq is that it is quite quick to abort with strange errors once you do something complex. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784135/347964) has usable code that solves the problem in Go if that helps you.

Comment: Which version of yq are you using? The Go or the Python version?

Comment: I tried using the latest Go version. I have now got it running using v3.4.1, which may be less powerful, but also a lot less complex. Any pointers as to how to get it to work with 4.x are appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Merging YAML files with `yq`, concatenating arrays.

### Assumption

In both `file1.yml` and `file2.yml`, the `animals` array contains a single index with a multiline string.

```
elephant
donkey
```

for `file1.yml`, and

```
monkey
pelican
```

for `file2.yml`.

Since you asked about **concatenated array**, I am assuming `file1.yml`, `file2.yml` and `results.yml` should be like this:

```
# file1.yml
animals:
  - elephant
  - donkey
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - chocolate
strange: true
```

---

```
# file2.yml
animals:
  - monkey
  - pelican
flavours:
  sweet:
    - vanilla
strange: false
```

---

```
# result.yml
animals:
  - elephant
  - donkey
  - monkey
  - pelican
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - chocolate
    - vanilla
strange: false
```

### Example

With `yq` 4.x, you can use the `ireduce` operator to merge two or more files:

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/reduce#merge-all-yaml-files-together

```
$ yq4 eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item)' file1.yml file2.yml
animals:
  - monkey
  - pelican
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - vanilla
strange: false
```

Both files have been merged, but duplicated keys and arrays have been overwritten by the latest file.

To appends arrays instead of overriding them, simply add a `+` after the merge operator (`*`).

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-appending-arrays

```
$ yq4 eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' file1.yml file2.yml
animals:
  - elephant
  - donkey
  - monkey
  - pelican
flavours:
  sour:
    - lemon
  sweet:
    - chocolate
    - vanilla
strange: false
```

Comment: I am having the similar requirement, how to merge and save into another file ? is it possible to write this content into another file ?

Comment: @DnyaneshwarJadhav. With yq ou can modify a file `--inplace`. When multiple files are used, only the first one will be modified.
Note that you can always redirect the output to another file:
`yq4 eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' file1.yml file2.yml > anotherFile.yml`

Comment: In terms of duplicate variable entries (like strange: false vs strange: true) the right most file wins. `yq4 eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' file1.yml file2.yml > anotherFile.yml` --> anotherFile.yml having strange: false, but `yq4 eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' file2.yml file1.yml > anotherFile.yml` --> anotherFile.yml would have strange: true

Comment: Thank you, @jpmorin! `yq eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)'` merges nicely ~/.kube K8s configs.