# Overlay and override two yaml documents with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I would like to overlay a yaml document on top another document, updating any arrays to be the overlaid values.

Given the base/source file:

```
#base.yaml
include:
  - directory: foo/foo1
  - directory: bar/bar1
```

and the overlay file:

```
#overlay.yaml
include:
  - directory: foo/foo1
    extra: true
    stuff:
      stuff1: true
      stuff2: true
  - directory: something/else
```

and the result should look like

```
#results.yaml
include:
  - directory: foo/foo1
    extra: true
    stuff:
      stuff1: true
      stuff2: true
  - directory: bar/bar1
  - directory: something/else
```

I think I am close to having it working with `yq` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694238/merging-two-yaml-documents-while-concatenating-arrays), but the list elements are not overridden.  I instead get duplicates of `foo/foo1`

`yq eval-all  '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' base.yaml overlay.yaml` produces

```
#base.yaml
#overlay.yaml
include:
  - directory: foo/foo1
  - directory: bar/bar1
  - directory: foo/foo1
    extra: true
    stuff:
      stuff1: true
      stuff2: true
  - directory: something/else
```

Removing the `+` after the `*` will drop `bar/bar1` from the output.

Basically I think I'm operating on the `include`, not the values of the `include` keys.  I would greatly appreciate any help in getting the overlay working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example here: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-arrays-of-objects-together-matching-on-a-key

Basically you will need to:

```
yq eval-all '
(
  ((.include[] | {.directory: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item )) as $uniqueMap
  | ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
) as $mergedArray
| select(fi == 0) | .include= $mergedArray
' sample.yml another.yml
```

Disclosure: I wrote yq

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the help, and the pointers to the docs.